# How return only value change from a mysql query without using php?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 mysql tables with 500.000 items

first with items price, items id, and ticket number
second with ticket_number, date of sales and total_price of ticket

by now i use this query

```
SELECT items.pri,ticket.date,items.crd,items.plu
FROM items ,ticket
WHERE 
(items.crd = 25 OR items.crd = 30) AND items.SeqNbr = ticket.SeqNbr
```

then in php:

```
$val_1 = array();
$price1 = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    if($row['crd'] == 25)
    {
        $prix = $row['pri'];
        if($prix != $price1)
        {
            $val_1[] = array( (int)$row['date']*1000,(float)$row['pri']);
            $price1 = $prix;
        }
    }
}
```

return:

```
[[1388552879000,1.519],[1389136505000,1.498],[1392420222000,1.514],[1394667334000,1.499],[1395373887000,1.478],[1395963467000,1.499],[1396649284000,1.52],[1397513210000,1.542],[1398384245000,1.556],[1399347974000,1.536],[1400910286000,1.553],[1403216692000,1.58],[1405029076000,1.563]]
```

goal is obtain an array with price change and date to build a charts of price fluctuation.

but with more than 500.000 records this is extremly slow (15 sec)

is there any possibilities to build mysql query that return the same array ?

Thanks

Comment: Use EXPLAIN to see where the bottlenecks are. Also make sure all the fields in WHERE conditions have corresponding indexes set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to check where is the bottleneck, on the query or on the loop. 
If it is on the query, check if you have the right index. If not, try adding index for the fields items.crd, items.SeqNbr and ticket.SeqNbr.